# Vertical Grouping - WPF DataGrid or ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

How can I have the below view by using WPF or creating a custom control?

[image: DatGrid]

As I need to use data templates and the cell values might be object instances, I cannot use WinForms to use the old structure. (Not to mention that even if I could I wouldn't!)

Grouping level can be one (like the picture) or more. Four steps is satisfactory here.

Any other solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/620909/How-to-merge-datacells-in-WPF-DataGridView

Comment: The sample you provided is using Windows Forms old structure. I need it in WPF using xaml and C# please.

Comment: See the post update. I need to use DataTemplates and all the things we have in WPF. Therefore it cannot be the old DataGrid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go

I defined an ItemsControl bound to Items (your data) and defined a group style to show data as your expectation.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".5" Padding="4">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                        </Border>
                                        <ItemsPresenter Grid.Column="1" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".5" Padding="4">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

here is the code to prepare the groups

```
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        Items.Add(new Item() { Key = "abcd", Data = 1 });
        Items.Add(new Item() { Key = "abcd", Data = 2 });
        Items.Add(new Item() { Key = "qwer", Data = 1 });
        Items.Add(new Item() { Key = "qwer", Data = 2 });

        CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);
        PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Key");
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

after this leave everything to WPF and enjoy the power of styling and binding

**Multilevel Grouping**

to achieve miltilevel grouping you simply need to add the PropertyGroupDescription to view.GroupDescriptions

eg

```
groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Key2");
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

[image: Multilevel group sample]

there is no limit of sub group you can create, all you need is a key to group.

Comment: What if I have three steps of grouping here?

Comment: you may need to define sub group style accordingly, nested grouping is fine.

Comment: I would look forward to have the appropriate data structure for that, and possibly the expected output too (screens, sketch etc).

Comment: As you can see the post description is updated to ask for more grouping steps which I think would be clear. Thank you.

Comment: assuming a grouping key (key2) in your flat data list i updated my answer, template remain same, it will nest accordingly.

Comment: Mate, one more thing to ask. Do you have any ideas about the column headers in the sample you provided?

Comment: using `ListView` with `GridView as it's view` instead of `ItemsControl` is the answer, it will help you define columns headers